# Use jQuery to submit ajax form after all ajax calls are complete

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using [this WordPress plugin](https://wpstorelocator.co/demo/) as a store locator on my website. On pages that do not have the interactive map, I have a form that that acts as a map search form.

In other words, I have a form with a location field. The user enters the location in the field and clicks the search button. When they click the search button, the page redirects to the page with the map and the location field is filled with the location entered on the previous page:

```
/* This is the search form on the page that does not have the interactive map */
$('#searchonly #wpsl-search-wrap form').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var loc = $('#searchonly #wpsl-search-wrap form #wpsl-search-input').val();
    localStorage.setItem("loc",loc);
    window.location.href = "http://localhost/inform/find-a-doc/";
});

/* This is the page with the interactive map */
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
    var loc = localStorage.getItem("loc");
    $('#wpsl-search-wrap form #wpsl-search-input').val(loc);
});
```

I now need the the search button on the page with the interactive map to automatically be clicked (or the form submitted) on page load.

There are a couple of roadblocks. The first is that I am using a WordPress plugin so editing the actual plugin files isn't an option. The second (this might not be a roadblock, I am not sure) is that the plugin is already running some ajax calls on page load. I would assume this means that the form submit button shouldn't be programatically clicked until the initial ajax is complete.

Here are the individual solutions I have tried. Each line break represents a different solution I have tried:

```
/* #wpsl-search-btn is the submit button for the form */

$(document).ajaxSuccess(function() {
    $("#wpsl-search-btn").submit();
});

$(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
    $("#wpsl-search-btn").submit();
});

$("#wpsl-search-btn").submit();

$("#wpsl-search-btn").trigger('submit');
```

None of those solutions are working and I am receiving no js errors in Chrome's inspector.

I'm not sure if this will help but here is the [plugin's main js file](https://pastebin.com/NnUaANQz).

Comment: Try using the `.trigger()` function e.g.`$( "#wpsl-search-btn" ).trigger( "click" );`

Comment: That does do something. It creates a submit loop. The form just keeps submitting over and over again.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at $.Deferred()
https://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/

You can bind promises that are executed after a request is processed.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Can you expand a little?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to answer my own question. This is the code that solved my problem:

```
var loc = localStorage.getItem("loc");
$('#wpsl-search-wrap form #wpsl-search-input').val(loc); 

function clickBtn() {
    $("#wpsl-search-btn").trigger('click');
}
$(document).one('ajaxComplete', function() {
    clickBtn();
});
```